# Update service based on enterprise database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

So I have an enterprise database on SQL Server which contains a feature class (only points)

I add this feature class to a new ArcGIS Desktop project, so there is only this layer in the project.

I then go to File -> Publish as a service and choose to publish it on ArcGIS Server.

I then go to the service definition and check on "ArcGIS.com Map View" that the service was published correctly.

Then comes my problem :

I add a new point to the Feature Class in the database, I check that the new point was added to the Feature Class without issues and it displays correctly on ArcGIS Desktop when I add the layer to the project (taking it again from the enterprise database).

I then check again the service published on the server, but the modifications I did in the database AFTER publishing the service aren't displayed.

Why does the changes I made in the Feature Class stored in the database (which the service is based on) aren't synchronized on the published service ?

edit : the layer owner is the user "DBO" and the layer was taken from the database connected as "DBO" (through ArcMap UI). The publishing was made by a user made specifically for publishing services. The layer isn't versioned and the database is on arcgis server. When I published I didn't change the default settings.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify if the layer is versioned and if the database connection is registered with Server. The complete output from the publishing request would be useful.

Comment: Have you published this to YOUR ArcGIS Server (and have set the data store)? Or are you indeed publishing it to ArcGIS.com?

Comment: The service is published on my ArcGIS Server. I don't use Portal for ArcGIS. I'll publish it later on ArcGIS Online with the REST URL.

Comment: You should *never*, **ever** publish anything as DBO -- this is a ***huge*** security risk. Instead, create a publishing user, and grant it the minimum possible access (just SELECT, usually), then connect with that user to register the server *and* publish the service.

Comment: sorry I meant when I get the layer from the database the user used to connect to the database is DBO but when I publish the service on the server there is a default publishing user.